# Defining a Set of Keys in Terms of Another Set of Keys

Tags: macros, pgfkeys, arguments

If I have 2 macros, one inside the other, while the top-most one has a bit more parameters, I would like to be able to set the top-most macro's keys as an extension of the bottom one, something similar to this (which doesn't work):

```tex
\pgfkeys{/phili/testA/.cd, 
  a/.store in = \a,
  b/.store in = \b,
  a           = a,
  b           = b,
}

\pgfkeys{/phili/testB/.cd, 
  \pgfkeys{/phili/testA/.cd, #1}
  c/.store in = \c,
  c           = c,
}
```

Is there a way of doing this with `pgfkeys`?

Here is a complete example:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\pgfkeys{/phili/testA/.cd, 
  a/.store in = \a,
  b/.store in = \b,
  a           = a,
  b           = b,
}
\pgfkeys{/phili/testB/.cd,
  a/.store in = \a,
  b/.store in = \b,
  c/.store in = \c,
  a           = a,
  b           = b,
  c           = c,
}

\newcommand{\testMacroA}[1][]{
  \pgfkeys{/phili/testA/.cd, #1}
  \a\b
}
\newcommand{\testMacroB}[1][]{
  \pgfkeys{/phili/testB/.cd, #1}
  \testMacroA[a = a, b = b] % If I use `\a` and `\b`, it gets stuck
  % I think it works if I just use `\testMacroA`, without arguments
  \c
}

\begin{document}
  \testMacroA[a = 1, b = 2]
  \testMacroB[a = 1, b = 2, c = 3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `\a` and `\b` keep redefined by themself. Could you use different macro name for `testA` and `testB` keys?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your comment. But the names in this example are more like placeholders, not constraints of the problem. I think it it is working if I just use `\testMacroA`, without arguments (I've added a comment to the code block).

Comment: @UlrichDiez in essence, all I would like to achieve is a way of making things more DRY. `\testMacroA` and `\testMacroB` both share the arguments `a` and `b`. I would like to define those once, instead of twice. The rest of the problem description has likely confused things, sorry. The key paths are not very important in this case either. The whole objective is to make this piece of code more maintainable, that's all. Does that clarify things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Edit: `\a`, `\b` and `\c` are already defined on the LaTeX 2ε-kernel. So let's use `\MyA`, `\MyB` and `\MyC` instead.)*

You can make keys defined for key-path `/phili/testA` but not defined for key-path `/phili/testB` also available via the key-path `/phili/testB` by using the key-handler `.search also`:

*(pgfkeys is a part of the TikZ/PGF-bundle which can be found on the [Comprehensive TeX Archive Network (CTAN)](https://ctan.org/) - the manual is at http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf. pgfkeys is described in part "Part VII Utilities", chapter "87 Key Management". `.search also` is documented in section "87.4.7 Handlers for Forwarding".)*

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\pgfkeys{%
  /phili/testA/.cd,  
    a/.store in = \MyA,  
    b/.store in = \MyB, 
  /phili/testB/.search also={/phili/testA},
  /phili/testB/.cd,  
    c/.store in = \MyC,
  % Define generic defaults:
    a = a,  
    b = b, 
    c = c,
}

\newcommand{\testMacroA}[1][]{%
  \begingroup
  \pgfkeys{/phili/testA/.cd,#1}%
  \MyA
  \MyB
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\testMacroB}[1][]{%
  \begingroup
  \pgfkeys{/phili/testB/.cd, #1}%
  % As \pgfkeys just (re)defined the macros \a, \b and \c
  % now run \testMacroA without in its optional argument
  % specifying those keys that (re)define one of those macros;
  % be aware that the things done by \testMacroA are done within
  % an extra group:
  \testMacroA
  \MyC
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
  \testMacroA

  \testMacroA[a = 1, b = 2]

  \testMacroB[a = 1, b = 2, c = 3]

  % This yiels an error as the key `c` is not defined
  % in the path `/phili/testA`:
  % \testMacroA[a = 1, b = 2, c = 3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

In case you wish to specify defaults for each key with each macro and have the defaults of `\testMacroA` overriden by what is specified with `\testMacroB` in case of `\testMacroB` producing the call to `\testMacroA`, you can probably do s.th. like this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\pgfkeys{%
  /phili/testA/.cd,  
    a/.store in = \MyA,  
    b/.store in = \MyB, 
  /phili/testB/.search also={/phili/testA},
  /phili/testB/.cd,  
    c/.store in = \MyC,
  % Define generic defaults:
    a = (GenericDefaultA),
    b = (GenericDefaultB),
    c = (GenericDefaultC),
}

\newcommand{\testMacroA}[1][]{%
  \begingroup
  \pgfkeys{/phili/testA/.cd, a=(testMacroADefaultA), b=(testMacroADefaultB), #1}%
  \MyA
  \MyB
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\testMacroB}[1][]{%
  \begingroup
  \pgfkeys{/phili/testB/.cd, a=(testMacroBDefaultA), b=(testMacroBDefaultB), c=(testMacroBDefaultC), #1}%
  % Providing an optional argument with \testMacroA is needed for overriding
  % \testMacroA's defaults with what is specified with \testMacroB - be that
  % \testMacroB's defaults or s.th. that comes from providing an optional
  % argument with the call to \testMacroB; also some expansion-trickery
  % is needed:
  \expanded{%
    \unexpanded{\testMacroA}[{a={\unexpanded\expandafter{\MyA}}, b={\unexpanded\expandafter{\MyB}}}]%
  }%
  \MyC
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
  \testMacroA

  \testMacroA[a = 1]

  \testMacroA[b = 2]

  \testMacroA[a = 1, b = 2]

  \testMacroB

  \testMacroB[a = 1]

  \testMacroB[b = 2]

  \testMacroB[c = 3]

  \testMacroB[a = 1, b = 2]

  \testMacroB[a = 1, c = 3]

  \testMacroB[b = 2, c = 3]

  \testMacroB[a = 1, b = 2, c = 3]

  % This yiels an error as the key `c` is not defined
  % in the path `/phili/testA`:
  % \testMacroA[a = 1, b = 2, c = 3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing stuff, @UlrichDiez. How did you find all that exactly? If possible, adding a reference would be helpful.